# JQuery & AngularJS - First object not recognized by selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

http://pastebin.com/HBGevwkV

In my view, I have a table.  Rows are generated by the `$scope.addScheduleElement()` function.  The  default/initial row is auto-generated by the `$(document).ready()` call.  After that, the user can click a button in the view to add more rows.

Each row of the table has its own color-picker element.  I used a `div` for the color picker which then gets an external color-picker framework applied to it.

For some reason, the jquery call that applies the color-picker properties to the elements with the `color-picker` class isn't registering the first row.  The call is seen in `modular.js` where it says

```
 $(".preview-circle").each(function(index,ele)
            {
                    initPicker(ele);
            });
```

When the default row is created, the color-picker won't work.  Then when I add more rows, the last row is always the one that doesn't work.  JQuery won't recognize the existence of the first `color-picker` class which I can tell because printouts in the `.each` call are only seen after manually adding rows.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Create a fiddle or plunkr, pastebin is useless.

Comment: wow, pastebin is indeed useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.addScheduleElement()` doesn't add a row. The row is added by `ng-repeat` afterwards.

The simplest thing to do:

```
elapse.controller('ScheduleController', function($scope, $timeout){
 ...
  $timeout(function() {
      $(".preview-circle").each(function(index,ele)
      {
        initPicker(ele);
      });
  });
```

That way the loop for `initPicker` runs later, when everything should be finished.

Comment: what function should this be in?  if I change `addScheduleElement` to have those parameters, `$scope` doesn't get passed in and neither does `$timeout`

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question.  The `$timeout` function is called once at the beginning of the page load.  I need to call the `.each` function every time the `ng-repeat` adds a new `li` element.  Is there some function I can use to do this?

Comment: @JasonMarmon  `initPicker($(".preview-circle:last")[0]);` only calls `initPicker` for the last element.

Comment: I need to apply the function to every instance of `preview-circle`, which requires calling the method every time `ng-repeat` is called/updated.  From my reading, it appears I should do this with a directive, but the `initPicker` method is inside of the Controller - something a directive wouldn't be able to access.  How would you recommend changing this around?  Thanks for all the help, by the way.

Comment: ahah! Figured it out!!! I moved the timeout inside the addScheduleElement function to ensure it was called every time.  Thanks again!